# Error in normal distribution graph

Tags: r

```
#Draw a normal distrubution graph 

mean = 0
sd = 1

#upper and lower value
ub = 0.5
lb = -0.5

x <- seq(-4,4,length = 100)*sd + mean
hx <- dnorm(x,0,1)

plot(x, hx, xlab = "Z-score", ylab = "Probability", 
     main = "normal distribution", axes = False)

i <- x >= lb & x <= ub
lines(x,hx)
polygon(c(0.5,x[i],0.5), c(0,hx[i],0), col ="red")

area = pnorm( 0.5,0,1) - pnorm(0.5,0,1)
axis(1, at=seq(40, 160, 20), pos=0)
```

I am trying to draw a normal distribution plot. However, I am getting the following error message:

> Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large??

I use R language

Comment: `x <- ...`? This does not look like Python.

Comment: It looks like **R**

Comment: I agree with the previous comments that this does not look like R. If it is indeed python, you should mention the library that you are using to clarify your question.

Comment: Sorry, it is R language